# open & closed sets; relative topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

my questions are not specifically related to any solid problems, but more of a general conceptual one.

As you know, a statement that a set is open or closed is a rather ill-phrased one (at least to me) in that *with respect to what set and what topology is such set open or closed*?

Thankfully, the topology I will ever be interested in talking about is that induced from metric. But... in statement like (the famous Heine-Borel theorem): *a set in metric space is compact iff every open cover of it has a finite subcover*.

Well, are those open sets open in where? Of course every set is open in its own topology (a set $A$ is always open and closed in $A$). Surely, this kind of problem is not only present in the statement of this particular theorem, but literally EVERYWHERE in the development of topology in metric spaces.

SO, how should I think of this issue?

Thank you all in advanced,

G.P.

Comment: At least with regards to compactness, there is the result that a subset $Y$ of a space $X$ has the property that for every open cover of $Y$ with sets open in $X$ if and only if $Y$ with the subspace topology is compact (so now we take open covers of sets open in the subspace topology).  It isn't very hard to do this by using the fact that a subset $V$ of $Y$ is open if and only if there is $U$ open in $X$ such that $V=U\cap Y$.

Comment: You don't really need subsets - compactness is just a statement about a topology, not about subspaces. In the case of compactness. @Hayden Basically, being a compact subspace is exactly  the same as the subspace topology being compact.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes, I was simply pointing out that it didn't matter whether you were looking at it "in" another space or if you were only looking at the subspace itself.  Specifically what I was paraphrasing was Lemma 26.1 in Munkres' Topology.

Comment: I don't find the statement that a set is open or closed as being *'rather ill-defined'*. Either one is given a specific topology to work with, in which case open sets are precisely the members of said topology, or else the topology is made implicit (such as when we speak of commonly encountered spaces $S^n$, $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$ etc.) in which case the open and closed sets are also apparent. If an author doesn't specify a topology in which open sets live, then it is probably because it's the obvious one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. $A$ is a compact subset of $X$ if and only if $A$ with the subspace topology is a compact subspace of $X$.

This is easy enough to prove from the definition of the subspace topology and the definition of compactness in terms of open covers. So the idea of a compact subset of a space, and of a compact subspace under the subspace topology, are equivalent notions and you will not need to worry about ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K\subset X$ a compact, and let $Y$ another topological space such as:

1. $K\subset Y$
2. $X$ and $Y$ have compatible topologies, that  is: 
   if $O_X$ is open in $X$ then $O_X\cap Y$ is an open set of $Y$ (and vice versa).

$K\subset Y$ is also compact:

Let $(O_i)_{i\in I}\in P(Y)^I$ be an $Y$-open cover of $K$.

For $i\in I$, $O_i\cap X$ is an open set of $X\cap Y$, and as $K\subset X$, $(O_i\cap X)_{i\in I}$ is an $X$-open cover of $K$, so there are $(i^1, \ldots, i^n)\in I^n$ such as $(O_{i^k}\cap X)$ is a (finite) $X$-open cover of $K$.

Conclusion: $(O_{i^k})$ is a finite $Y$-open cover of $K$.

So as far as compactness (in Borel Lebesgue fashion) is concerned, this question is not that important.